# How to make my image carousel loop instead of returning back

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on an image carousel and I have ran into a problem. The automatic function of my slider does not work as I want it to. When the slider reaches the last image, it goes all the way back to the first image revealing the images between instead of looping back to the first. What can I add to my code to achieve that? Here is the relevant code.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-container">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';

var interval = 3000; // 1000 = 1 sec
setInterval(function() {
    var offset = counter % (carouselImages.length - 2);
    carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone';
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
    counter++;


    if (offset == 0) counter = 1; // to reset counter so next and prev button should work 

}, interval);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a working demo so we can see the problem?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I am really sorry. I am very new to stack overflow. May you please elaborate on what you mean by a working demo? Sorry.

Comment: [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Online sandbox & demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MerkUriy/gdk268ey/latest/) for original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Add twoClone after firstClone in HTML.
2. Immediately after step "last → firstClone", turn off the animation and jump to slide "first". After that, turn on the animation and going the normal carousel.

HTML:

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" alt="" title="lastClone">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" alt="" title="first">
        <img src="./img/testpic2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" alt="" title="last">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" alt="" title="firstClone">
        <img src="./img/testpic2.jpg" alt="" title="twoClone">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector(".carousel-slide");
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-slide img");

const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");

let counter = 1;
let durationAnimation = 400; // ms
let activeAnimation = "transform " + durationAnimation + "ms ease-in-out";
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
const updateSlideTransformX = () => {
  carouselSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + -size * counter + "px)";
};
const changeActiveAnimation = off => {
  carouselSlide.style.transition = off === false ? "" : activeAnimation;
};

updateSlideTransformX();

let interval = 1000; // 1000 * 3 sec
setInterval(function() {
  // enable animation
  if (counter === 1) changeActiveAnimation()
  
  // to next slide
  counter++;
  updateSlideTransformX();

  if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 2) {
    counter = 1;
    setTimeout(() => {
      // disable animation & jump to slide 1
      changeActiveAnimation(false);
      updateSlideTransformX();
    }, durationAnimation);
  }
}, interval);
```

[Online sandbox & demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MerkUriy/hfv8bega/latest/).

́

---

Additional solution — back-and-forth carousel.
[Online sandbox & demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MerkUriy/qhajez17/latest/).

Comment: Improved solution and online sandbox & demo.